# ¿Como pasar de un fragment a otro en un orden definido en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity

Tengo un MainActivity que contiene un boton, dentro de ese mismo Activity tengo 3 fragments, el Fragment1 es el que aparece visible al abrir la app, lo que hago ahora es esto;

```
//Controlamos las acciones de los botones flotantes
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int id = view.getId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.fab:
            animateFAB();
            break;

        case R.id.fab_enviar:
          showDialog();
            break;

        case R.id.fab_agregar:
           if (container.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
               segundoContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                container.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            break;
    }
}
```

En el botón fab_agregar,hago una condicion if, que si el Fragment1 (en este caso container) esta visible, ahora pase a ser invisible y que el Fragment2 pase a ser visible, hasta ahi funciona todo bien, ahora, como puedo hacer para pasar al Fragment3? Porque si lo hago de la misma manera no tiene sentido, ya que si condiciono que el Fragment1 este invisible y Fragment2 este visible para pasar al Fragment3, pasara directo a ese Fragment desde el primero, obviando el segundo. Alguna idea?

Adjunto pantallas de la app, la primera imagen, seria el Fragment1, que como ven es una serie de inputs, el boton flotante de agregar, llama al Fragment2 (segunda 
 imagen) que tiene tambien una serie de inputs, el tercer fragment es parecido, con inputs.

[image: Fragment1] [image: Fragment2]

Comment: Pero que es lo que planeas con esto, podrias hacer eso con un `Navigation_Drawer`, adjunta una imagen también para ver como tienes ordenado el `Activity`.

Comment: **El objetivo de los Fragments no es hacerlos invisibles/visibles  es realizar transacciones para cambiarlos**.

Comment: Adjunta un pantallazo de tu app para antender mejor el flujo que esperas. De entrada puedo observar que la mejor forma de hacer esto es creando una lista de fragments List<Fragment> y usango un fragmentManager para hacer un replace de los fragments sin tener que estar ocultando containers lo cual no esta para nada bien hecho.

Comment: Ya está, agregue las pantallas de la app para que puedan entender mejor lo que deseo hacer

Comment: son Fragments o DialogFragments o combinación? Cual fragment de inicio lanza la activity? Agrega el código del MainActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
    List<Fragment> data;
    Int cont = 0;
    @Override
    onCreate(Bundle savedInstace){
       data = new Arraylist<>();
       data.add(Fragment1)
       data.add(Fragment2)
       data.add(Fragment3)
}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        switch (id){
            case R.id.fab:
                animateFAB();               
                break;

            case R.id.fab_enviar:
              showDialog();

                break;

            case R.id.fab_agregar:
               if (cont < data.size()){
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()                  
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,data.get(cont++)//Aqui iria el fragment que deseas que se muestre);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                         }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Como mencione antes el manejo debes hacer con un fragment manager. La informacion mas detallada de como hacerlo esta en la documentacion oficial que seria esta

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Mucha suerte y espero te funcione

Comment: Entiendo, pero el problema es que quiero hacer la transición de fragments desde un mismo botón, el fab_agregar, que primero pase del fragment1 al 2, del 2 al 3, del 3 a 4 y asi sucesivamente

Comment: Cual serie el boton que quieres que te cambie los fragments?

Comment: Revisa la logica que uso ahora con una lista de fragments y un contador

Comment: @JhonFredyTrujilloOrtega Genial! Funciono! Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Si esta respuesta te funciono te agradezco que por lo menos le des un punto jajaja.  y si crees que es la respuesta correcta, la marques como tal. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ya se que es un tema cerrado, pero me gustaría dejar mi ejemplo..

Creamos las respectivas clases ***'creamos un total de 3'*** que hereden de `Fragment 'android.app.Fragment'` con su respectivo método `onCreateView` que apunten o inflen su contenedor

`return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);`

---

Por otro lado tenemos nuestro contenedor principal que será donde se vayan alojando los respectivos Fragment con un ID 'contenedor_pequeno'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/contenedor_pequeno"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.diego3l.fragmentsdiego.MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Bienvenido Fragments!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:elegantTextHeight="true"
        android:text="Quiero un fragment"
        android:onClick="dameFragments"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Y por otro lado tenemos la Clase principal que es la encargado de ir intercambiando los respectivos fragments, los 3 que tenemos, con el respectivo botón, que irá cambiando a cada pulsación, con una simple variable contador.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int contador = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    public void dameFragments(View view) {
        ExampleFragment1 fragment1 = new ExampleFragment1();
        ExampleFragment2 fragment2 = new ExampleFragment2();
        ExampleFragment3 fragment3 = new ExampleFragment3();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();//comenzamos transacción

        if (contador == 0) {
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.contenedor_pequeno, fragment1);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            contador++;
        } else if (contador == 1){
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contenedor_pequeno, fragment2);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            contador++;
        } else if (contador == 2){
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contenedor_pequeno, fragment3);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            contador = 0;
        }

    }
}
```

---

Y este es el aspecto de los Fragments en nuestro contenedor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Genial el ejemplo, y como harias en caso de que en la clase principal haya un boton que necesita de los EditTexts que estan en todos los fragments?

Comment: Esa pregunta puede tener muchas respuestas y no es tan sencilla de responder. Si tienes algo en mente podrías formular una nueva pregunta y seguro que se te podría ayudar. He visto que el sistema no te deja dar votos positivos, jajaja. Saludos!.